# Can't share image on google+ android

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, share, android-resources

I am trying to share an image with description to google+ using this code:

```
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    Uri image = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ahmed.mostafa.testgplus/"
            + R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    iv.setImageURI(image);

     PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(this);
     share.setText("Hi G+");
     share.setType("image/jpeg");
     share.addStream(image);


     startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(), 0);
```

The ImageView iv shows the image.But when Google+ dialog show up the description "Hi G+" appears but the image don't.

What's wrong with my code.I got it from [Here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/media)

Answer (score 1):

Google+ apparently does not support the `android.resource` scheme. That is a rather unpopular scheme, and many apps will not support it. Share your content by other means (e.g., `FileProvider` and a `content://` scheme, or a file on external storage and a `file://` scheme).

Comment: All Images I want to share are drawables.Is there a way to share ?? .... can i use this `Resources res= getResources();
Drawable drawable= res.getDrawable(R.drawable.photo);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, drawable, opts);`

Comment: @ahmedghanayem: You can write your own streaming `ContentProvider` to share them. Or you can use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to share them. Or you can write them to files and share them.

Comment: Thank you i will try it.

Comment: The documentation specifies that [EXTRA_STREAM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) should contain a `content://` URI. By using anything else you're asking for trouble.

Comment: @CommonsWare I write them to a file and then share the and it works. Thank you it takes me the whole day to learn it.